# Android volley error request code 415 with Rest API?

Tags: android, android-volley

## Server side:

```
    import flask

    import flask.ext.sqlalchemy

    import flask.ext.restless

    app = flask.Flask(__name__)

    app.config['DEBUG'] = True

    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'

    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=True
    db = flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(app)

    class Person(db.Model):

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.Unicode, unique=True)
        birth_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    class Computer(db.Model):

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.Unicode, unique=True)
        vendor = db.Column(db.Unicode)
        purchase_time = db.Column(db.DateTime)
        owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
        owner = db.relationship('Person', backref=db.backref('computers',
                                                             lazy='dynamic'))

    db.create_all()

    manager = flask.ext.restless.APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)

    manager.create_api(Person, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])

    manager.create_api(Computer, methods=['GET'])

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

## Client Side :

**Using volley post**

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // response
                        Log.d("Response", response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error

                        Log.d("Error.Response", String.valueOf(error));
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", "Anything");

                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add( postRequest );

    }
```

## Output from log:

> 04-29 11:42:24.556 1890-1946/? I/Icing: Indexing done F3642025687382E430F3465743F12480D56AAC66
>       04-29 11:43:32.123 3147-3196/? E/Volley: [157] BasicNetwork.
>       performRequest: Unexpected response code 415 for http://IP:5000/api/person
>       04-29 11:43:32.132 3147-3147/? D/Error.Response: com.android.volley.ServerError
>       04-29 11:45:19.365 1298-1311/? I/UsageStatsService: User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk

Comment: Did you set the content type in the header?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

provide the right content type as follows

```
    // Optional Parameters to pass as POST request
    JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
    try {
        js.put("name","anything");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Make request for JSONObject
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, url, js,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString() + " i am queen");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
        }) {

        /**
         * Passing some request headers
         */
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjReq);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

415 is the error code for wrong media type. You are sending the body or your post request in plain text when the server expects json. Find out what type of content you should send and make the post body to that type.

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() {
    return 'your json string'.getBytes(); 
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
}
```

Comment: I had used this also but it didn't  worked I need a code if you can provide .

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Kotlin, here is the snippet I implemented

```
 val jsonBody = JSONObject()
    jsonBody.put("email", email)
    jsonBody.put("password", password)
    val requestBody = jsonBody.toString()

    val registerRequest =
        object : StringRequest(Method.POST, URL_REGISTER, Response.Listener { response ->
            print(response)
            complete(true)

        }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            Log.d("Error", "not possible to register at this time . $error")
            complete(false)


        }) {
            override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            override fun getBody(): ByteArray {
                return requestBody.toByteArray()
            }
        }

    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(registerRequest)
}
```